# Yify torrent api returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently came across the Yify-torrents api at [YifyTorrentAPI](https://yts.re/api#listDocs) and just thought let's give it a try with jquery and create a little own application. I used the following code to retrieve the upcomming movies list which worked.

```
$.getJSON("https://yts.re/api/upcoming.json", function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(item, value) {
                        console.log(value.MovieTitle + ' ' + value.ImdbLink);
                    });

                });
```

on the other side when I tried to get all the movies list using the following request I just got undefined in the console.

```
$.getJSON("https://yts.re/api/list.json", function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (item, value) {
                        console.log(value.MovieTitleClean + ' ' + value.ImdbLink);
                    });

                });
```

I am sharing the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9g7/1/) in which I have wrote the code. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: because its returning different json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second ajax call is returning movies in a `MoviesList` object so you need to iterate on `data.MovieList` not `data`.

JSON:

```
{
 "MovieCount":4921,
 "MovieList":
[{
 "MovieID":"5372",
 "State":"OK",
 "MovieUrl":"https:\/\/yts.re\/movie\/Gun_Woman_2014_1080p",
 "MovieTitle":"Gun Woman (2014) 1080p","MovieTitleClean":"Gun Woman",
 "MovieYear":"2014",
 "DateUploaded":"2014-06-30 00:10:03",
 "DateUploadedEpoch":1404043803,
 "Quality":"1080p",
 "CoverImage":"https:\/\/static.yts.re\/attachments\/Gun_Woman_2014_1080p\/poster_med.jpg",
 "ImdbCode":"tt3141912",
 "ImdbLink":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt3141912\/",
 "Size":"1.24 GB", 
 "SizeByte":"1335275815",
 "MovieRating":"8.2",
 "Genre":"Action",
 "Uploader":"OTTO",
 "UploaderUID":"310615",
 "Downloaded":"35173",
 "TorrentSeeds":"20",
 "TorrentPeers":"24497",
 "TorrentUrl":"https:\/\/yts.re\/download\/start\/777FD07DAD285CB06846CAFD97600B07F2CC88B3.torrent",
 "TorrentHash":"777fd07dad285cb06846cafd97600b07f2cc88b3",
 "TorrentMagnetUrl":"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:777fd07dad285cb06846cafd97600b07f2cc88b3&dn=Gun+Woman&tr=http:\/\/exodus.desync.com:6969\/announce&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80\/announce&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:1337\/announce&tr=udp:\/\/exodus.desync.com:6969\/announce&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.yify-torrents.com\/announce"
  }]
}
```

do like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://yts.re/api/list.json", function (data) {
                        console.log("Getting all the movies");
                       // console.log(data)
                        $.each(data.MovieList, function (item, value) {
                            console.log(value.MovieTitleClean + ' ' + value.ImdbLink);
                        });

                    });
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/8673m/)

Comment: welcom @JamalHussain glad it helped